# How to solve negative binomial regression?

Tags: regression, optimization, negative-binomial-distribution, approximation

I want to estimate negative binomial regression for from scratch i.e. I want to write a script that will maximize maximum likelihood obtaining optimal parameters. To do so we can calculate derivatives and force them to be equal to 0.

**Question**

To estimate negative binomial regression we are looking for zeroes of those two expressions:

[image]

My question is - how can I now find such parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that will find zero of a function os those two expressions? ($\beta$ is inside $\mu$)

My first idea was to denote first expression as $A$ and second expression as $B$.

Then we are looking for such $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that $A = 0$ and $B = 0$. The equivalent problem to consider is $A^2 + B^2 = 0$ and now we can use newton raphson method to find zero of this function. However, I find this solution little tedious since I have to calculate $\frac{\partial^2(A^2 + B^2)}{\partial \alpha^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2(A^2 + B^2)}{\partial \beta^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2(A^2 + B^2)}{\partial \alpha \beta}$ to obtain Hessian. Is there any easier way to solve it?

Comment: Why don't you directly aplly an optimization algorithm to the log-likelihood function, e.g. Nelder-Mead (does not require derivatives)?

Comment: By imposing such artificial constraints on the solution method, you have framed this as a self-study exercise in applied mathematics rather than as a problem in statistics or machine learning.

Comment: What do you mean by artificial constraints?? Those are exactly the conditions that negative binomial model is estimated from.